# Convert text string in wrong format to date with in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this sql table in which I have a column with dates, but they are text strings and they are not in YYYY-MM-DD format. My dates are in DD/MM/YYYY.

How can I parse or convert those text strings into dates **DD/MM/YYYY --> YYYY-MM-DD** ?, Preferably in a new column, since I will be updating that table with new CSVs with the wrong date format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like

```
UPDATE t 
SET my_truly_is_date_col = STR_TO_DATE(my_wonky_stringdate_col, '%d/%m/%Y')
WHERE my_wonky_stringdate_col LIKE '%/%/%'
```

i.e. you'll make a new column that really is a date, then fix all the strings into it, then remove the string col, then fix the program that loads the junk in so it uses the date column and everything is beautiful going forward? Yep.. That'd be good ;)

Comment: Lol I won't be able to "fix the program that loads the junk" since it is a manual download csv > upload csv :( and files are too big to change them in Excel.

But i guess the solution you gave me can work if I run it every time I update my DB, right? :( yes i know it is SAD

Comment: I use sequel pro to upload my CSVs is there a way to fix the string at the same time??

Comment: mysql infile can also rewrite column when you import it, so write a sql script for that

Comment: Often for those situations where you can't change some aspect (well, I suppose we can always change some aspect, even if it means writing another app to load our db) you might consider it better to have some temporary or staging table, you load all your crazy data into there and then move it into the final table your app uses with an INSERT query that cleans up the data, the. You can delete the temporary data and you're not having to keep the bad alongside the good. If the importing app can do this processing even better but all in it amounts to the same  thing..

Comment: .. "read file, write bad data to somewhere temporary, write good data to somewhere permanent" - there's probably not a right or wrong answer to "where should the temporary data go"; if you need to pull in other db data to patch it up then in the db is a good place, but ends up it's going to be deleted when the process is over so put it wherever your life is made most easy

Answer (score -1):

> SELECT STR_TO_DATE('[ 21/Apr/2009:07:14:50 +0100]', '[ %d/%b/%Y:%H:%i:%S +0100]');

Comment: you can choose this type and you can get date format

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).